# How to stop hiding buttons forward / backward in pagination?

Tags: php, widgets, pagination

I am doing pagination on my site. For this, I use the get_the_posts_pagination function. Now, the back button is hidden on the first page, and the forward button is hidden on the last page. How do you prevent them from hiding?

Comment: Or did you want them visible but disabled?

Comment: @Rup yes I want them to be visible but not active. It doesn't make sense, but that's how it is set on the layout